# How to solve HTTPS response 498 when googlebot comes along?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, googlebot

I have an AJAX site leuker.nl and when googlebot comes along the site is started and it will retrieve an XML file from my backend server that contains site text.

The HTTP GET request used to retrieve the file returns a HTTP error 498.
Looking on [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) it explains that is concerns an invalid/expired token (esri) returned by "ArcGIS for Server".
I don't understand this error, I don't even use ArcGIS and never heard of it before.

Andy idea how to solve this?

In the backend I use Apache Httpd 2.4 in combination with Tomcat 8.0. Apache proxy requests to Tomcat through an ajp connector. The XML file requested is directly returned by Apache.